# Почему Hashtable не возвращает тот тип который в него добавлен

Tags: c#, .net

Есть переменная Hashtable, в нее добавляются List<>. Почему при выводе из Hashtable выводится не List<>?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Hashtable catalog = new Hashtable();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)//просто создаётся лист с двумя структурами-мусик и добавляется в каталог-Хештейбл
    {
        List<Music> disk = new List<Music>() {
            new Music() { Author = $"a{i}", Song = $"asong{i}" },
            new Music() { Author = $"b{i}", Song = $"bsong{i}" }
        };
        //PrintDisk(disk); //тут не ругается и всё работает
        catalog.Add($"Disk{i}", disk);                
    } 
    //PrintDisk(catalog["Disk1"]);//ругается а на верху перед добавление нет
    Console.ReadKey();
}

struct Music
{
    public string Author;
    public string Song;
}
static void PrintDisk(List<Music> disk)
{
    foreach (Music x in disk)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Author: {0, 10}; Song: {1, 8}", x.Author, x.Song);
    }
}
```

Comment: Приводить вручную надо к типу, там по сути хранятся `object`. Потому советуют использовать Dictionary, а не таблицу хэшей.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пишите так `PrintDisk((List<Music>)catalog["Disk1"]);`

По ключу из `HashTable` достается `object`, а метод у вас принимает на вход `List<Music>`, поэтому нужно кастить к своему типу.
Или используйте `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`.

Comment: Тоже подумал что нужно юзать дирректори. Но в лабараторной дан этот тип коллекции. Блин, а я пробовал в начале преоброзовать её так.... Видимо ошибку допустил и подумал что не робит

Comment: @LORD - лабораторная методичка наверняка давным-давно устарела.

Comment: @LORD: Нетипизированный `Hashtable` — это мезозой. Нет смысла не использовать `Dictionary`.